# How to position links at specific radius in a D3 Radial Reingold–Tilford Tree?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm using the code from Mike Bostock's [Radial Reingold–Tilford Tree](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550) pretty much as the example, but would like to control the position (just the radius) of the nodes according to a variable contained in each element of the JSON data.

I can do this for the nodes like this (using a linear scale on the variable I mentioned):

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + scale(d.variable) + ")"; })
```

But I can't figure out how the start and end positions of the links (which need to correspond with the nodes) are being controlled by the `diagonal's` default [projection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#diagonal_projection):

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
  .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI]; });
```

Can anyone explain how this projection works, and what I should do to modify it to make the links start and end at a specific radius?

Comment: If you have the position of the nodes already, there's no need to run the layout.

Comment: I have a distance from the centre for each node, but was letting the algorithm work out the angular position. On thinking about it, I guess it could be more straightforward than I thought to work this out. However I still don't understand the default diagonal's projection (e.g. what the initial value of `d.x` is and where it is generated, what the `d.x / 180 * Math.PI` does, and why the projection returns y before x...

Comment: The tree layout works on Cartesian coordinates; the things you mention convert them on the fly to polar coordinates.